# Pearson Coefficient Correlation in R (time series

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, economics, pearson-correlation

I am getting these errors when I am trying to find the Pearson Correlation.

1. Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
   only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables
2. The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!

```
library("ggplot2")
library(corrplot)
corrplot 0.92 loaded
Dataset1 <- read.csv('C:/Users/sha03/Desktop/R/intro/data/FULL2.csv')
corrplot(Dataset1)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables
corrplot(Dataset1, method= "number", type= "upper")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables
> corrplot(Dataset1)
Error in corrplot(Dataset1) : The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!
> corrplot(Dataset1, method= "number", type= "upper")
Error in corrplot(Dataset1, method = "number", type = "upper") : 
  The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!


date    country A   AA      AAS1     AAS2    AAS3
1997 Q1 1   6.06    -20.04  -0.05   0.9     1.87
1997 Q2 1   7.66    26.23   0.04    1.24    2.44
1997 Q3 1   6.63    -13.37  -0.08   1.13    1.28
1997 Q4 1   4.38    -33.95  -0.03   0.96    1.83
1998 Q1 1   -3.19   -172.8  -0.01   0.99    1.99
1998 Q2 1   -7.26   127.77  0.01    0.95    1.96
1998 Q3 1   -6.38   -12.1   -0.09   1.02    1.94


How can I fix this problem?
```

Comment: As I can see from your dataset, you have variables that are not usable inside the corrplot function. Exclude the first two columns like this : Dataset1 <- Dataset1[,-c(1,2)], after reading in your csv. Then you can try to run the function again on the data. All columns must be numeric

Comment: I tried this: Dataset1 <- Dataset1[,-c(1,2)]
and im still getting the error: The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!
i tried manually removing the columns and row, still the same error

Comment: Ah! i figured it out, corrplot(cor(Dataset1), method= "color", type= "upper", order = "hclust"). this code seems to work!